# Windows.location.reload() not working in react js app hosted in hostgator

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web-hosting

I deploy a React js app in a Hostgator but I can use the `Windows.location.reload()`,

When the screen is reload through `Windows.location.reload()` only show a 404 error screen, but if I press f5 shows the component. This happens only the firts time that I open de app, when I refresh te code its working and not show the 404 error screen.

Someone knows why this happens, in local host if it works.

Comment: Could be a CORs issue. What is the error message?

Comment: shouldnt it be `window.location` ?

Comment: I dont know what happend, I modified nothing, I just went for a coffee and coming back I did not show the error.

Comment: but but the error only said that it could not find the page (404 error), this happened only in the hosted application and only the first time the windows.location.reload () was used.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
window.location.reload()
```

This is my demo https://jsfiddle.net/huynhsamha/jkymh8sq/

```html
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/huynhsamha/jkymh8sq/4/embed/js,html,css,result/dark/"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

setting `window.location` to the current `window.location` will reload the page. you can try as, `window.location = window.location`.